# IIS Cold Start / State After 10 Minutes

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm having "cold start/state" issues with my IIS (& ASP.NET Core API). After around 10 minutes of idleness, if I make a request to my IIS, I get issue "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: curl. curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset" OR on Fiddler "HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure". After making that request, if I make more requests, it works fine. It's just the first request that doesn't work.

I have tried everything I have found: StartMode to AlwaysRunning, doAppInitAfterRestart (preload) with a non authenticated controller/endpoint, setting application pool idle timeout to 0 (and process suspended instead of terminated), disabling application pool recycling (set to 0)

Extra context in case it helps:

1. I am using BasicAuthentication (configured in code) - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-basic-authentication-api/master/Helpers/BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs
2. I am using Entity Framework Core & SQL Server (injected into the controller from the endpoint I am calling)
3. I am using IIS on Win Server 2022. Jenkins for CI/CD. Don't use linux because I have unit tests with Selenium/Chrome automations, which I want to be able to see in action. Don't use Kestrel since I have found it really hard to integrate with Jenkins (for start/stop), and since I like hosting my Angular app in the same "context/program"

Since using IIS I have had nothing but headaches. I have worked with Python/Flask, Gunicorn, Jenkins and its been a breeze, but I really wanted to make .NET work for my startup, so I've pushed on and on through headache and headache. I cannot for the life of me sort this last issue out.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated

Comment: Is this full fat IIS, self hosted on eg a collocated serv/vps? Have you considered a cloud provider like azure? Takes a lot of the headache out of this.. For azure when you configure always on, it just sets up a monitor job that calls every few minutes. If you're running your own service you might want something similar that will send you an alert if your site goes down, and the 5 minutely check from eg uptime robot will keep your site alive anyway

Comment: Even if you have set up everything you found, such as StartMode, doAppInitAfterRestart, application pool idle timeout and recycling, but you still have "cold start/state" issues? You've mentioned using doAppInitAfterRestart which is essentially preloading the application.  You can also try creating a warm-up script that periodically makes requests to your API to keep it alive.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.